# DateListPlot shaded area between Gridlines

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, filling, grid-lines

I have been trying to figure out how to shade between Gridlines and I couldn't on my own, but found [this post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1006718) that almost has the perfect response except that the spaces between the frame and the first/last points are not shaded, like you can see on the image.

[image]

Tried editing the code presented in the webpage but they all led to errors or the shaded box not being visible anymore.

Could anyone indicate a way of accomplishing a full shading between gridlines? Be it from this code or in any other way?

Thank you!

```
data={{"Mon 23 Jan 2017 12:41 PM",152},{"Mon 23 Jan 2017 12:44 PM",146},{"Mon 23 Jan 2017 6:11 PM",143}, {"Mon 23 Jan 2017 6:14 PM",142},{"Tue 24 Jan 2017 5:47 PM",135},{"Tue 24 Jan 2017 5:51 PM",126}, {"Wed 25 Jan 2017 6:22 PM",129},{"Wed 25 Jan 2017 6:22 PM",109},{"Thu 26 Jan 2017 12:47 PM",137}, {"Thu 26 Jan 2017 12:49 PM",132},{"Thu 26 Jan 2017 6:36 PM",141}};
thePlot = DateListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {80, 180}}, 
   GridLines -> {None, {60, 85, 100, 140}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin], ImageSize -> 540];
gr = Graphics[{Opacity[.1], Blue, Rectangle @@ Transpose[{First[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[thePlot, PlotRange]], {100, 140}}]}];

Show[thePlot, gr]
```

PS: I am copying the snippet of code from the post because I am importing the data from a `.csv` file.

Comment: try `Show[thePlot, gr, PlotRangePadding -> 0]`?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) with [`DateObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) locations on the date-axis in [`DateListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html).

Therefore you can

1. get the
   [`DateBounds`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateBounds.html)
   on the date-axis,
2. expand this date range to cover the padded plot
   range,
3. plot the
   [`Rectangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html).

The expanded date rage by 1 day on both ends can be obtained with [`DatePlus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DatePlus.html) and [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html) by

```
Inner[DatePlus, DateObject /@ DateBounds@data[[All, 1]], {-1, 1}, List]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then the above in `DateListPlot`'s `Epilog` with `Rectangle`

```
DateListPlot[data,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {80, 180}},
 GridLines -> {None, {60, 85, 100, 140}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin],
 ImageSize -> 540,
 Epilog -> {Opacity[.1, Blue],
   Rectangle @@
    Transpose@{
      Inner[DatePlus, DateObject /@ DateBounds@data[[All, 1]], {-1, 1}, List],
      {100, 140}
      }
   }
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the you can also use [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) if you want the shaded area plotted first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`Scaled[]` along with `AbsoluteTime[]` is usable in `Rectangle[]`, which allows us to produce the following plot:

```
DateListPlot[data, GridLines -> {None, {60, 85, 100, 140}},
             GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin], Joined -> True, 
             PlotRange -> {Automatic, {80, 180}}, 
             Prolog -> {Opacity[0.2, Blue], 
                        Rectangle[Scaled[{-1, 0}, {AbsoluteTime[data[[1, 1]]], 100}], 
                                  Scaled[{1, 0}, {AbsoluteTime[data[[-1, 1]]], 140}]]}]
```

[image: plot with shaded area]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `` Charting`get2DPlotRange[thePlot `` to get the plot range taking into account plot range paddings and use it to specify the rectangle coordinates:

```
gr = Graphics[{Opacity[.1], Blue, 
 Rectangle @@ Transpose[{Charting`get2DPlotRange[thePlot][[1]], {100,  140}}]}];

Show[thePlot, gr]
```

[image]